# Get all items in JSON and put them in an array

Tags: json, swift, alamofire

I am using Alamofire to get some JSON data and rather than having everything hardcoded, I was wondering how to simply include everything in the array.

Currently, this is the JSON file:

```
{"One":"Item1","Two":"Item2","Three":"Item3","Four":"Item4","Five":"Item5"}
```

My swift code:

```
var pickerData: [String] = [String]() //Array of content.
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://example.com/file.json").responseJSON{ (response) -> Void in

if let JSON = response.result.value{
let One = JSON["One"] as! String
let Two = JSON["Two"] as! String
let Three = JSON["Three"] as! String
let Four = JSON["Four"] as! String
let Five = JSON["Five"] as! String
self.mypickerview.delegate = self
self.mypickerview.dataSource = self
self.pickerData = [One, Two, Three, Four, Five]
...
```

How can I not make them hardcoded so that I can have my file like this and it would still work and include everything in the JSON, even if I add more in the future:

```
{"Item1","Item2","Item3","Item4","Item5","Item6"}
```

Comment: this has got nothing to do with your swift programming. you need to change the structure of your JSON output. Place it in a loop with fixed headers.

Comment: For an indeterminately sized, ordered collection, your JSON should be structured using an array, for example like this: `{"items":["Item1","Item2","Item3","Item4","Item5"]}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aaron is right, your JSON should use an array to hold the item values.

But if you're stuck with this format, you can get the values in your `pickerData` like this:

```
if let JSON = response.result.value as? [String:AnyObject] {
    let result = JSON.values.flatMap({ String($0) })
    self.pickerData.appendContentsOf(result)
    self.pickerData.sortInPlace()
}
```

`pickerData` is now:

> ["Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4", "Item5"]

and items will be sorted in the picker array even if you add new ones later.

Comment: I highly appreciate this answer, but it seems to be having some issues [link](http://i.imgur.com/BjQwNGm.png) The result constant  says "Cast from '[AnyObject]' to unrelated type 'String' always fails

Comment: @Matt I've changed my answer, check the new code, it should be ok now.

Comment: @Matt Previously it didn't work because I forgot to cast the response as a Swift dictionary in the `if let`. // Note that I've used `flatMap({ String($0) })` but `flatMap({ $0 as? String })` would also work now, thanks to said casting.

Comment: I just tested it and it can confirm that it is working now! Thank you so much for your help! I'll have the bounty updated soon!